# bootstrap remove vertical space from rows of thumbnail's grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to remove vertical space between the rows of a thumbnail's grid as I did for that horizontal but with no success.

```
.gutter-0.row {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    /* not working */
    margin-top: 0; 
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.gutter-0 > [class^="col-"], .gutter-0 > [class^=" col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    /* not working */
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="row gutter-0">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row gutter-0">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/7k3xXDUmXR)

How could I do?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a margin bottom on the "thumbnail" classes.

Just add this to your css to remove it :

```
.thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/yYJG6NgZVg)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`.thumbnail` has 20px bottom margin. Either reset it or use the below style.

```
.thumbnail{
  display: table-cell;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/hDnBumWAdZ

Comment: Also your solution is ok. Thanks